# ¿Qué es "posma"? ¿De dónde viene la palabra?

Tags: etimología, españa, adjetivos, palabras-raras

Leyendo *Zalacaín el aventurero* del escritor español Pío Baroja me encuentro con este fragmento:

> Martín acompañó a la muchacha, y cuando la vio sola la estrechó por la cintura y la besó en la mejilla.
>
> —¡También usted es **posma**! —exclamó ella con desgarro.
>
> —Es que usted es navarra y con sal, y yo quiero probar esa sal —replicó Martín.
>
> —Pues tenga usted cuidado no le haga daño. ¿Quién lleva usted en el coche?

Para más contexto, tanto el autor como la obra se localizan en el País Vasco y el libro se publicó en 1909. El Martín de la anécdota es Martín Zalacaín, protagonista del libro. Este es un tanto descarado y lanzado, por lo que lo que indica el DLE no me acaba de encajar:

> [**posma**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TnvWaSH)
>
> 1. f. coloq. Pesadez, flema, cachaza.
> 2. m. y f. coloq. Persona lenta y pesada en su modo de obrar. U. t. c. adj.

Además, [en el IEDRA](https://iedra.es/palabras/posma) veo que apareció en el DLE en 1822 y se la vio por primera vez en 1611 en el *Origen y etymología de todos los vocablos originales de la Lengua Castellana* de Francisco del Rosal. Además, se observa una disminución en su uso, pasando de poco en el siglo XIX a casi nada últimamente.

Pero pese a toda esta búsqueda, no encuentro etimología alguna ni explicación clara de qué significa. Para mí, sería algo así como "descarado", si bien se podría tomar lo de "persona lenta y pesada" como una ironía, pues Zalacaín es todo lo contrario a la hora de besar a la mujer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El diccionario de Terreros y Pando (1788) define **posma** como

> Lo mismo que pesado, molesto.

lo que cuadra mejor con el sentido del texto.

Sobre la etimología he encontrado en el **diccionario de Rosal (1611)** una explicación de la que no entiendo ni jota:

> Posma dicen a la persona pesada y gruesa, del Griego, que proverbialmente decía *Pleumon* del torpe y perezoso, de donde el latino dixo *Pulmo* al Pulmón, conforme a lo cual se entiende Plauto (in epid.) quando dice *Pedibus pulmoneis ...* donde Pies pulmoneos entiendo como en Plinio Poma pulmonea, de donde parece venir **posma**. De esto habló más Scaligero en los Catalectos de Virgilio.

Por otro lado **Corominas** recoge (retoco el formato y resumo algo):

> POSMA, 'pesadez, flema', voz familiar, probablemente resultante de una alteración de *pasmo* en el sentido de 'pasmado'; quizá se trate de una deformación intencionada, de carácter jergal, por trasposición de las dos vocales. 1<sup>a</sup> doc.: fin del S. XVIII, Terr., Gz. del Castillo, L. F. de Moratin; Acad. 1843, no 1817.
>
> Terr. (¿h. 1764?) define «pesado, molesto»; Morcuende cita los dos pasajes siguientes pertenecientes, respectivamente, a los otros dos autores: «¡Me desespero! ¡Qué *posma*! Si la pillara / la ahogaría entre mis dedos», «¿Aún no se ha marchado el viejo? / ¡Qué *posma*!».

Corominas inserta a continuación varias teorías etimológicas, que rechaza:

> Se han propuesto varias etimologías... Spitzer [del francés], Piel el greco-lat. *APŎZĚMA* 'cocimiento' ... En realidad el defecto peor que tiene la etimología de Piel, tanto como las de Spitzer, es la de suponer un punto de partida demasiado antiguo para una voz tan reciente, y que siendo percibida por todo el mundo como un término vulgar y casi jergal, ha de ser de creación moderna.

Para concluir en su idea inicial:

> Mucho más razonable es la idea de Spitzer de relacionar con *pasmado*, voz del mismo significado y de igual tono estilístico que *posma*. Podría pensarse en *pasmoso* > *posmoso* por dilación vocálica, y luego una regresión *posma*.
>
> También puede pensarse que *posma* sea abreviación jergal de **posmarote* por *pasmarote* 'estafermo', *pasmarota* 'acto de fingir la enfermedad del pasmo' [Aut.]. Todo viene a parar en lo mismo.
>
> Y aun me parece mejor, puesto que de palabra jergal se trata, un fenómeno de criptolalia, de deformación intencional de *pasmo* en *posma*, comparable a las metátesis por «truquage» que encontramos ya en la germanía de Juan Hidalgo, como *greno* por *negro* y *chepo* por *pecho*.
>
> El *posma* fué primero el bobalicón distraído o de pocos alcances a quien engañaban los rufos. Que luego se atenuara algo el sabor jergal de *posma* y entrara en el estilo familiar, es algo que a nadie llamará la atención.

Comment: Caramba, cuánta posible definición y origen para una palabra que ya pasó a mejor vida. Muchas gracias por la investigación, Rotten.